# RubyMine: Unresolved Ruby Reference for global variable

Tags: ruby, global-variables, rubymine

Running RubyMine 2016.2.4. This project has a "global" singleton called `$environment`. All over the codebase this file is `require_relative`'d to get access to runtime dependencies. RubyMine is showing "Unresolved Ruby Reference" for every instance of `$environment` in classes which use this global.

Mock-up of how the `environment.rb` file looks:

```rb
require 'singleton'

class Environment
  include Singleton
  def log
    ...
  end
end

$environment ||= Environment.instance
```

Example usage which RubyMine complains about:

```ruby
require_relative '../environment'

class FancyWorker
  def run
    ...
    $environment.log.info 'Running!'
  end
end
```

I've tried searching to no avail on how to resolve this inspection problem in RubyMine. I don't want to disable the inspection since it is useful for finding legitimate problems - but this is not a legitimate issue.

(Please keep commentary about globals being bad to yourself, I didn't make that design decision - I just want to help RubyMine understand the reference.)

Comment: Rubymine uses yard documentations. Maybe it helps with your global variable too `# @type [Environment]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found a bug on RubyMine. Try changing:

```
$environment ||= Environment.instance
```

to:

```
$environment = $environment || Environment.instance
```

or just assign it if you're sure you won't be defining `$environment` anywhere else.

Comment: You may be correct about a bug in RubyMine. Using the `$environment = $environment || Environment.instance` seems to have solved the issue.